# Wrong raster layer size with custom CRS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I am trying to create a raster layer in QGIS with a custom CRS.  When I measure the distance of the equator it is wildly incorrect. The distance should be `38,563.0258` km but comes out anywhere between `2`km and `200,000`km.

I am trying to create an equirectangular projection.

The CRS is `+proj=eqc +a=6158.143 +b=6137.496 +unit=m +no_defs`

Comment: Isn't it a small world with 6 km radius?

Comment: Give +a and +b in meters instead or set +unit=km.

Comment: I guess it is similar in size to venus. The circumference is c. 38,000km. Does a and b mean radius or circumference?

Comment: Did you already use either `+a=6158143 +b=6137496 +unit=m` or `+a=6158.143 +b=6137.496 +unit=km`?

Comment: a and b are parameters for an ellipsoid. I guess these have to be in meters, regardless of `+units`.